# all imports are unused Geolocation ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation

All imports are unused.

```
   L1:  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   L2:  import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
```

please somebody help me i'm tired, i read that removing "declaration.d.ts" file will solve this but i dont know how to remove this file and where it is

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is just change tslint.json 's

```
 "no-unused-variable": [
      true
    ]
```

to

```
 "no-unused-variable": [
      false
    ]
```

This will solve your problem